# RetroPie only has 6 emulators

Tags: retropie

I already have downloaded RetroPie 3.0, 2.6, compiled by myself in Raspbian,selected the option to install a emulator from binary and source.

I always only have 6 emulators available to me.
(Macintosh, IBM, apple2, ScummVM, AMIGA and Ports)

How do I make the other emulators available to me?

Comment: Hello and welcome! Here's a question: what is your question?

Answer (score 5):

That's because those emulators come with `roms` installed by default. You have to add `roms` in order to see the emulators.

The easiest way to transfer `roms` to the `RetroPie 3.0` SD card is to take a freshly formatted USB stick (Fat32) and create a folder called "retropie". Then connect USB it to the `rasberryPi`. This will create a file structure on the USB.

Once this file structure is created, take the USB back to your computer and add your `roms` to the respective folders inside the "retropie" folder. After you put the USB back into the `rasberryPi`, the system will auto sync the `roms` into the system. Then reboot the system and the emulators will show up with the roms installed.